# Bash: bind -x messes up terminal?

Tags: bash

When I run a program as usually everything is fine, but when I run it via keybinding (`bind -x '"\C-]":qr'`) terminal is messed up?

Thats the program: https://github.com/naquad/QuickRun

How to fix that? Is that a program fault? Or bind?

Comment: Define "terminal is messed up". Without the command installed, I simply get a "command not found" error, so I doubt there is anything wrong with the binding.

Comment: escape sequences (functional keys, Ctrl+L, arrows, etc...) are not evaluated, but printed as is

Comment: It's certainly the program. I see that it uses some sort of console interface library (`urwid`) that is would affect your terminal. Without looking at the code too closely, I'm not sure what benefit it provides over what can be done directly in shell.

Comment: this is definitely related to bash itself. program i execute from qr is ssh and it looks like thats the main problem

Comment: It's probably related to the value of the `TERM` environment variable, not `bash` itself. `bash` is not involved with how characters are displayed in your terminal.

Comment: its not TERM, its not even related to urwid. try this: bind -x '"\C-]":ssh somewhere' - you'll see what i mean

Comment: Ah. It appears that the `-x` option to `bind` is intended for non-interactive programs. Using your `ssh` example, everything looks OK except that my input is not echoed to the screen.

Comment: yes, I've got help at irc://irc.freenode.net/#bash

Answer (score 1):

It figures out that bind -x is not indented to run interactive programs or programs that use TUI (curses and similar). To run such program one should use a macro:

`bash '"\C-]":"\C-u\C-kyour command\C-j"'`

this is for emacs mode. Key by key:

- `\C-]` - keysequence to bind
- `\C-u\C-k` - clear line (first one - delete until cursor, second one - delete after cursor)
- command
- `\C-j` - accept line aka enter